# Can this solution be improved?

Tags: php, string, comparison

I have written a PHP code for finding common letters in two strings. Currently it has a complexity of `O(n^2)` can it be optimized.

```
<?php

$b="AMITABH BACHHAN";
$a="RAJNIKANTH";

$cmnlet="";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($a);$i++)
{  
   for($j=0;$j<strlen($a);$j++)
   {
       //echo "a=".$a[$i]." b=".$b[$j];
       if((strcmp($a[$i],$b[$j]))==0)
       {

            $cmnlet.=$a[$i];
            //echo "commonletter ".$cmnlet;
       }    
    }
}

echo (implode(array_unique( str_split($cmnlet))));
?>
```

Comment: If the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: https://eval.in/712106

Answer (score 1):

```
$as = str_split ( $a, 1);
$bs = str_split ( $b, 1);
$result = implode(array_intersect($as, $bs));
```

edited as suggest by @Gougata Bose:

```
$result = implode(array_unique(array_intersect($as, $bs)));
```